# A table of images and captions & the captions doesn't appear organized

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm making a section called "online shop" in my website. I thought about the way to display the products and "table without borders" was the one that came to my mind. I made it but part of the caption is hidden under the product's image. Is there a way where I can fix it or try anything other than table without borders?

```
<table>   <tr>
    <td><figure>   <img src="cartt.png" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="130" height="130">   <figcaption>French Manicure<br/>150SR<p
style="color:green;">In Stock</p></figcaption> </figure> </td>
    <td><figure>   <img src="cartt.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="130" height="130">   <figcaption>French Manicure<br/>150SR<p
style="color:green;">In Stock</p></figcaption> </figure></td>
    <td><figure>   <img src="cartt.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="130" height="130">   <figcaption>French Manicure<br/>150SR<p
style="color:green;">In Stock</p></figcaption> </figure></td>   </tr> 
<tr>
    <td><figure>   <img src="cartt.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="130" height="130">   <figcaption>French Manicure<br/>150SR<p
style="color:green;">In Stock</p></figcaption> </figure></td>
    <td><figure>   <img src="cartt.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="130" height="130">   <figcaption>French Manicure<br/>150SR<p
style="color:green;">In Stock</p></figcaption> </figure></td>
   <td><figure>   <img src="cartt.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="130" height="130">   <figcaption>French Manicure<br/>150SR<p
style="color:green;">In Stock</p></figcaption> </figure></td>   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please demo the problem, ideally in a JSfiddle.net demo

Comment: Create an online demonstration of the issue using your current HTML   and CSS at [**Jsfiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net/) and give us the generated link. At present your code **should** work but without seeing what else you have going on it's hard to help.

Comment: I runit, how can i give it to u?

Comment: Not the wholepage...just enough to demonstrate the problem. SO users **hate** wading through unnecessary code just to find one tiny issue...[**Make a SSCE**](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as using something other than a table without borders, I tend to fall on the 'div' side of the [table vs. div debate](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/), so I would suggest considering `div`s in place of your `table` layout; however, since you started with a table, my code snippet below uses a table as well.

I did not see the problem you described in your question (caption obscured by the image); however, there were a few typos and extra/wrong characters that were making your output look strange (extra `>`s throughout, `style` attributes outside of tags, etc.). Perhaps you have CSS that you did not post with your initial question? In any event, here is a snippet with your code tidied up a bit and displaying your content as I presume you want to see it.

```css
img.productTumbnail {
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
}
span.inStock {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.foodsafety.gov/images/sys_images/widget_tip_images_SEP.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
        <figcaption>French Manicure
          <br/>150SR
          <span class="inStock">In Stock</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

    <td>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.foodsafety.gov/images/sys_images/widget_tip_images_SEP.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
        <figcaption>French Manicure
          <br/>150SR
          <span class="inStock">In Stock</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="productThumbnail" src="http://www.foodsafety.gov/images/sys_images/widget_tip_images_SEP.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
        <figcaption>French Manicure
          <br/>150SR
          <span class="inStock">In Stock</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
  >
  <tr>

    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="productThumbnail" src="http://www.foodsafety.gov/images/sys_images/widget_tip_images_SEP.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
        <figcaption>French Manicure
          <br/>150SR
          <span class="inStock">In Stock</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="productThumbnail" src="http://www.foodsafety.gov/images/sys_images/widget_tip_images_SEP.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
        <figcaption>French Manicure
          <br/>150SR
          <span class="inStock">In Stock</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>

    <td>
      <figure>
        <img class="productThumbnail" src="http://www.foodsafety.gov/images/sys_images/widget_tip_images_SEP.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
        <figcaption>French Manicure
          <br/>150SR
          <span class="inStock">In Stock</span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```